# Как зарегистрировать несколько моделей на один URL

Tags: python, django, django-urls, mptt

только начал тыкать джангу, и вот возникла надобность писать урлы, и не хочется, чтоб в урлах были эти слова вроде "shop", "page", "category"
Поэтому у меня 2 вопроса

1. Как правильно регистрировать пути, если к примеру у меня для каждой записи есть slug и будь то просто страниа, или запись блога или товар магазина, категория записи/товара путь примерно один:
   `path('<slug:slug>')`
   Насколько я понимаю, что если просто так и писать, то в целом проблем не будет, но хотелось бы узнать как делать лучше, чтоб не писать плохой код
2. У меня вложенные категории, я использую mptt_urls, но никак не могу заставить его работать как нужно, а именно, я в модель категории добавил:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products:category', kwargs={'path': self.get_path()})
```

Документация дает такой пример для урлов:

```
import mptt_urls

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^gallery/(?P<path>.*)', mptt_urls.view(model='gallery.models.Category', view='gallery.views.category', slug_field='slug', trailing_slash=True), {'extra': 'You may also pass extra options as usual!'}, name='gallery'),
    ...
)
```

я записал вот так:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<path>.*)', mptt_urls.view(model='products.models.Categories', view='products.views.categories', slug_field='slug', trailing_slash=True), name='category')
```

но это не помогло, ссылки как были в виде
http://site.com/category_slug
так и остались такими же

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы настроить урлы для вашей модели категорий, вам нужно добавить соответствующий путь в файл urls.py. Например, если у вас есть модель Category

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('categories/<slug:slug>/', views.category_detail, name='category_detail'),
]
```

Так же если у вас есть вложенные категории, вы можете использовать библиотеку django-mptt для удобного построения древовидных структур категорий.

```
from mptt_urls import urlpatterns as mptt_urls
from . import views

app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
    # другие пути
]

urlpatterns += mptt_urls(
    'categories',
    views.category_detail,
    slug_field='slug',
    tree=models.Category.tree.all(),
    trailing_slash=True,
)
```

Comment: да, спасибо
1) такой способ знаю, но тогда ссылки будут вида
site.com/categories/<slug>
а я хотел бы 
site.com/<slug>
на всех страницах и на категориях тоже

2) да, я как раз ее и использую, не могу добиться вложенного урла, по вашему примеру не получилось
в библиотеке mptt_urls нет urlpatterns там только класс view лежит